# How can I create variables in Python using other variables?

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, python-3.5

The main premise is to get both teams' names and display an icon behind them, so I created dictionaries like

```
home_team = {'home_foo': '[](#icon-foo) Foo'}
away_team = {'away_bar': '[](#icon-bar) Bar'}
```

My question is, how can I input a team's name, and create a variable called `home_'team name'`, so I can use the dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you might just want to do something like this:

```
teams = {}

team_name = input("Enter your team name: ")
teams[team_name] = ...
```

Just replace `...` with the specific value you want for that key.